# Google sheets script (javascript) compare loop ignoring bottom 2 rows in spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I wrote a script that compares rows between two sheets and deletes all matching rows on the second sheet (named 'temp'). I set the loop to start at the end of temp and decrement, working toward the top.  The script works but it ignores the bottom two rows on 'temp'...how can I fix this? I want to ensure it will delete the bottom two rows on temp when they match the data set from the other sheet.

I have confirmed that the bottom two rows are in fact duplicates and should be caught by the script and deleted.

Script:

```
function trimTempSheet() {

  var ss, s, s1, dt;
  var dirname='X DIR'
  var fs, f, fls, fl, name;
  var ncols=1,i, newRows, rw;

  ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  s=ss.getSheetByName('Report Results');

  name = 'temp';

  //Load current sheet to compare  
  var currentDataSet = s.getRange("A:S").getValues(); //Ignore final columns
  var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);

 //Load imported data to compare
  var newData = newSheet.getRange("A:S").getValues();
  var headers = newData.shift();

//Create empty array to store data to be written [to add later]
    newRows=[];

//Compare data from newData with current data
  for(var i = newData.length-1; i > 0; --i) 
       { 

for(var j in currentDataSet)
  {
         if(newData[i].join() == currentDataSet[j].join()  )
    {
        newSheet.deleteRow(i);
     }
  }
          }
```

Comment: If `currentDataSet` is an array, you should use a normal `for` loop, rather than `for..in`. [See this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/215552) for more.

Comment: I switched the inner loop to: for(var j = 0; j < currentDataSet.length; j++), but it still ignores the bottom two rows of 'temp'.

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### From :

```
for(var i = newData.length-1; i > 0; --i)
```

#### To :

```
for(var i = newData.length-1; i >= 0; --i)
```

#### Note :

- About "the bottom two rows on 'temp'",

  - By above modification, one loop is added to the for loop.
  - In your script, the first element of `newData` is removed by `var headers = newData.shift();`. By this, `newData` decreases one element.

    - For example, how about also removing this line?

If this modification was not useful for you, I'm sorry. At that time, can you show us your sample spreadsheet?

Comment: When I remove the header shift, my script now deletes duplicates except in the final (bottom) row of the sheet. So thank you, I am halfway to a solution.  However, the script is still ignoring the bottom row--even when I change i to greater than or equal to zero. I tried changing to "newData.length", without subtracting one, but that produces an error "cannot call method 'join' of undefined"....why does length-1 work but length is undefined here for this array?

Comment: @SancheyV I'm sorry. I couldn't understand your current situation. If your problem was solved, I'm glad. If your problem was not solved, can you show us your sample spreadsheet and your current script?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the optimal way to force the script to look at and delete the last row first, without skipping it. So I changed the delete line to "newSheet.deleteRow(i+1);"

Will this produce any unintended row deletes based on my iteration loops? I am not an expert at how google scripts handles arrays. I assume the loops will examine rows in newData (the sheet named 'temp) sequentially, from the last row to the first. In which case my solution would be acceptable. But I am not certain of this.